# check array against each other, to determine response

Tags: php

So, I have an array that has 6 variables in it that I need to check against each other..  to determine what to return to the script calling the function..  All fields are of the `datetime`  type from the database they are derived from.

the fields: `in1` `out1` `in2` `out2` `in3` `out3`

Array:

```
Array(
  'in1' => '2012-04-02 10:00:00), 
  `out1` => '2012-04-02 14:00:00`,
  `in2` => '2012-04-02 14:30:00`,
  `out2` => '2012-04-02 18:00:00`,
  `in3` => NULL,
  `out3` => NULL
)
```

the response:

`clocked_in` or `clocked_out`

What I need to figure out is, the best way to determine if the user is clocked in or clocked out by checking against this array..

so, if `in1`, `out1` and `in2` are not NULL then the user would be clocked in..  if `in1` is not NULL but `out1` is NULL then the user would be clocked out, etc..  Anyone have any ideas on the easiest way to achieve this without too many if statements?

[WHAT WORKED]

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    if ($entities["in$i"] != NULL) {
        $ents = "clocked_in";
        if ($entities["out$i"] != NULL) {
            $ents = "clocked_out";
        }
        if ($entities["out3"] != NULL) {
            $ents = "day_done";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more information about how exactly each of the fields gets populated would be helpful.

Comment: Initially in the DB it looks like:

2012-04-02 10:00:00 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is treat them as pairs. You should loop through your array two at a time checking to see if the clock in is set, and if so, is the clock out set. Update a variable along the way to make sure.

```
$clocked = '';
for($i=0; $i <= sizeOf($arr); $i+2) // $arr is your array of clock in and outs
{
  if(arr[$i] != NULL)
  {
      // Our Clock In is Not Null and Our Clock Out is.. meaning we're clocked in.
      if(arr[$i+1] == NULL) // check clock out
      {
         $clocked =  "clocked in";
         break; //Break out so we don't check the other pairs because we know we're clocked in.
      }
      else //Clock Out Exists, so far we're clocked out.
      {  
         $clocked = "clocked Out"; // We can't break here. There might be more clock in/out pairs left to check.
      }//end clock out check
   }// end clock in check
}// end for loop

echo $clocked;
```

Its kinda rough as I wrote this up pretty quickly. I apologize if there are any syntax errors but this is the basic concept I'd use.

Comment: Nice idea but won't work..  array looks like:  `array(in1 => date, out1 => date, in2 => date, out2 => date, in3 => date, out3 => date)` where `date` is either a valid datetime or NULL

Comment: your code confused me just a little bit...  but i restructured it, and it worked perfectly.. code is in my OP..

Comment: Ah yea, I didn't realize you had "in1" and the rest as your array keys. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more stylish way of doing it, without nests:

```
# the fields as array $a: in1 out1 in2 out2 in3 out3

function is_clocked_in( $a ) {
    $c = (count(array_intersect( $a, array(null) ))) % 2;
    return( $c ? true : false );
}
```

Theory behind this is that number of null fields gets returned by array_intersect; after that, you find out it that number is even or odd, which implies the clocked-in/out state. Example uses "t" to signify a non-null value, but it's meant to be a string timestamp.

```
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( null, null, null, null, null, null ) ) );   // f
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", null, null, null, null, null ) ) );    // T
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", "t", null, null, null, null ) ) );     // f
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", "t", "t", null, null, null ) ) );      // T
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", "t", "t", "t", null, null ) ) );       // f
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", null ) ) );        // T
var_dump( is_clocked_in( array( "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t") ) );          // f
```

Comment: That, is a very stylish and possible way to do it...  I might have to try it out..

Comment: Oh, nice use of the array_intersect. I like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution is at the schema level; you could modify the database to be an activity log, instead of using a concrete series of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Occurrence` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `OccurredOn` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `Type` ENUM('IN','OUT') NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

<sub>(*forgive the brevity*)</sub>

Now you can support an arbitrary number of clock-in/out occurrences, in the event requirements change.

Finding the state of a user is just selecting the most recent occurrence record, and checking the `Type` field.

You can validate at the application level, such that if the most recent occurrence state is `IN`, then you can only insert an `OUT`, and vice versa.

Use a trigger to auto populate the `DATETIME` field, or use `TIMESTAMP` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default (*though I forget the specifics of that*)

Comment: possible but this would require re-writing most of the entire application to fix one issue of always showing the right button.. so thanks for the input,  but its not plausible.

Comment: @Johnny No problem; I figured that you may not be able to change the schema given other parts of your application were dependent on it, but it's a consideration worth making :)